# How can I install Sybase ASE 15.5 step by step?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, database

If anyone has successfully installed Sybase ASE 15.5 on Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04 please share your installation process step by step.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586556). This may be of help.
How to install Sybase ASE on Ubuntu Linux from the forums